# Fail jinja2 rendering if any variable was not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I have a case where we define some config templates and the user provides variables to fill the environment-specific variables to fill the templates. The templates have hundreds of variables and it is possible that users can miss some variables. Is there any way to fail the rendering if any of the variables are used in the template and they are not defined or provided by the user?

Comment: What does it currently do about these missing variables?

Comment: please post a [repro] to demo your question.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: what you are asking is the default behavior - Jinja2 automatically fails rendering (by throwing errors) if *any* variable used in the template is undefined.

In Jinja2, rendering will fail by default if *any* variable is missing... you can supply variables that are not used in the template, but if any variable that is used in the template is not defined, it will always throw an error.

See [the Docs](https://svn.python.org/projects/external/Jinja-1.1/docs/build/scopes.html#undefined-variables):

> Starting with Jinja 1.1 it's possible to replace the default undefined
> object with different values. The other common undefined object which
> comes with Jinja is the ComplainingUndefined object.
>
> **It raises exceptions as soon as you either render it or want to    iterate over it or try to access attributes etc.**

Comment: So, while technically an error is not automatically thrown, the second you try and render the template, an error will be thrown.